# Python canvas colour change by button

Tags: python, user-interface, button, canvas, colors

I am a python self learner. I was stuck on some practice.
My idea was to create a pop out GUI with buttons that can change the canvas colour.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()
root.title("Colour!")

canvasColor = "yellow"

def buttonRed() :
    canvas = Canvas(root, bg = "red", height=100, width=100) 
    canvas.grid(row=0,column=2)

button = ttk.Button(root, text="Red", command = buttonRed)
button.grid(row=2,column=1)

button2 = ttk.Button(root, text ="Green", command = buttonGreen) 
button2.grid(row=2,column=2)

button3 = ttk.Button(root, text="Blue", command = buttonBlue)
button3.grid(row=2,column=3)

canvas = Canvas(root, bg = canvasColor, height=200, width=200) 
canvas.grid(row=0,column=2)


root.configure(background='white')
root.mainloop()
```

i haven't put in the green and blue button command yet, but instead of creating a new canvas when the colour button clicked, i just wanted to have the default canvas colour change.

Any help will be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need -

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()
root.title("Colour!")

canvasColor = "yellow"

def buttonRed() :
    canvas.config(background="red")

def buttonGreen() :
    canvas.config(background="green")

def buttonBlue() :
    canvas.config(background="blue")

button = ttk.Button(root, text="Red", command = buttonRed)
button.grid(row=2,column=1)

button2 = ttk.Button(root, text ="Green", command = buttonGreen) 
button2.grid(row=2,column=2)

button3 = ttk.Button(root, text="Blue", command = buttonBlue)
button3.grid(row=2,column=3)

canvas = Canvas(root, bg = canvasColor, height=200, width=200) 
canvas.grid(row=0,column=2)
#canvas.config(background="black")

root.configure(background='white')
root.mainloop()
```